# How do i remove an Announcements Entry Constants in Liferay Social Office announcement

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

I've just started using Liferay and there is this social office announcement. When adding/editing and entry, there is a form which comes up with a Type droplist. This has General, News and Test currently.

How/where do i edit such that I can remove the "Test" option

In the code I see this where it gets the list for the droplist

```
AnnouncementsEntryConstants.TYPES
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update below property in your portal-ext.properties to remove test from drop down

announcements.entry.types=general,news